# How to change the default character set of mysql using docker-compose?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

When I save the string of Chinese, mysql rise the error "Exception Value:
(1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xE5\xB0\x8F\xE6\x98\x8E' for column 'name' at row 1")",I check the character of mysql,it show this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And my docker-compose.yml is as fellow:

```
web:
    image: yetongxue/docker_test:1.2
    links:
      - "db"
    ports:
      - "8100:8000"
    volumes:
      - "/Users/yetongxue/docker_v/docker_test/media:/root/media"
    restart: always

db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerasdf
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/Users/yetongxue/docker_v/docker_test/db:/var/lib/mysql"
```

I know how to set the character of mysql with my.cnf,but how can I do this in the docker-compose.yml?
Anybody know this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking this. It's silly that the image defaults to latin1!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can either build your own mysql image where you modify my.cnf, or modify the command that starts mysql's daemon with `--character-set-server=utf8mb4` and `--collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci`.

```
web:
    image: yetongxue/docker_test:1.2
    links:
      - "db"
    ports:
      - "8100:8000"
    volumes:
      - "/Users/yetongxue/docker_v/docker_test/media:/root/media"
    restart: always

db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerasdf
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/Users/yetongxue/docker_v/docker_test/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
```

I recommend using utf8mb4, as it can store up to "4 bytes per multibyte character" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Comment: [ERROR] COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Comment: try with character-set-server = utf8

Comment: For people getting here in the context of K8s here is what youe need to append to the `spec.containers`: `args: ["--character-set-server", "utf8mb4", "--collation-server", "utf8mb4_unicode_ci"]`

Comment: Great answer, even though the `mysqld` command is not necessary. If you use instead `command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']`, it will also work.

Comment: Why this does not work for `image: mariadb:10.8.3`?

Answer (score 15):

I read the GitHub issue as @Ziemowit Stolarczyk listed. All of them are not exactly correct. The GitHub answer is `-e LANG=C.UTF-8`. I use it in my docker-compose.yml, but mysql prints out like this:

```sql
mysql>  show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

It doesn't work for database and server. So I add a configuaration in docker-compose.yml as the following.

```yaml
command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The whole yaml file is:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      LANG: C.UTF-8
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is the final output.

```sql
mysql>  show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## REFERENCE

- https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/131#issuecomment-248412170
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419629/13430829

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted to create your own docker image with the settings above, instead of specifying them in docker-compose, you can do so like:

```
FROM mysql:5.5.60

RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime

VOLUME ["/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"]

CMD ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake"]
```

Comment: Why do you need `skip-character-set-client-handshake`?

Answer (score 6):

The answer of @Javier Arias is great but still, some non-utf8 settings are left on my site like below.

```
mysql> show variables like "%char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

It was causing some issues related to the utf8 characters displaying after `docker-compose exec mysql bash` and making queries.

After adding one ENVIRONMENT setting: `LANG: C.UTF_8` I get:

```
mysql> show variables like "%char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

So I think the final docker-compose.yml should be:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerasdf
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_db
      LANG: C.UTF_8  # this one should be added
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/Users/yetongxue/docker_v/docker_test/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

You can read the whole thread related to this here https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/131.

Comment: If I may, the var env of LANG should be C.UTF-8 (with dash)

Answer (score 4):

Most of answers are good, but probably the best docker-compose with right charsets and great structure I have found is [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/pull/14#issuecomment-234293551).

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./sql-scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      - --skip-character-set-client-handshake
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
```

The result:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Also SQL (and `.sh`) files in the `sql-scipts` directory will be executed during startup (e.g. to import your existing dump at the first container start)

Answer (score 1):

The compose file is used for running containers (and can build images). You cannot customize the images inside the docker-compose file. You need to create a custom image that extends the **mysql** image.
Create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
RUN <command to update my.cnf>
```

Then build this image:

```
docker build -t <image-name> .
```

Update compose file:

```
db:
    image: <image-name-specified-above>
```

Comment: Yes, this is  a effective method. I have found the method I wanted just now,you can set in your docker-compose.yml like this:  command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8'] .  Here is the example link: https://coding.net/u/twang2218/p/docker-lnmp/git/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

try with character-set-server = utf8

```
docker run --name mysql-server -t -e MYSQL_DATABASE="docker_db" -e MYSQL_USER="username" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="qwerasdf" -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="YjA0OTYwZDBiN2EwNWFjMTRjZGU3Yjcy" -d mysql --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_bin --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this by setting command in docker-compose.yml

```
command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
```

in a lot of variations, but it didn't work for me for any magic reason. My tables collations and collation of connection were still `latin1_swedish_ci`, although collation_server was `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I solved it by setting this options to mysql config file (my.cnf) directly and setting my.cnf as volume.

my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=testuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=testpassword
    volumes:
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

p.s. my.cnf is placed near docker-compose.yml in this example. You can put it in another folder, but you should change path in volumes part

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
db:
image: mysql:8.0
restart: always
environment:
  LANG: C.UTF-8
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
  MYSQL_DATABASE: web_servicedb
  MYSQL_USER: myuser
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
  MYSQL_INITDB_CHARSET: utf8mb4
```

LANG parameter makes the magic, also check this issue: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/131

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34627793)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my SQL-dump file had been exported without UTF-8 encoding and I had to manually fix the dump to have the correct characters.